# How do I get identical network adapters to use different drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm using an Ubuntu 18.04 box as my LAN gateway, firewall and reverse proxy and it has three identical USB WiFi adapters (one on the LAN side and a bonded pair on the WAN side). I'm experiencing poor connectivity more often recently and the stock driver from the manufacturer does not get as good signal quality as some of the customized versions people have posted on GitHub.

I have compiled a few different versions of the driver from different sources and with different settings, but running just one driver at a time on all three interfaces is an almost useless way to compare the drivers. So I'd like to benchmark the drivers simultaneously while they are responding to the same network conditions and events. If not all three at once, then at least two at a time would suffice.

How do I get a specific piece of hardware to load a specific .ko file? (Identifying the interfaces by MAC address would be great, if that's an option.)

Thanks in advance!